# Getting index of list within a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv, key-value

I have created a key:value pair from a csv, where the value is actually a list of all the rows of data, i.e
[image]

has now become:

Date ['04-Nov-22', '05-Nov-22']

USD [0.9872, 2.9872]

JPY [145.19, 11115.19]

I get the above results by doing:

```
for key,value in df.items()
    print(key,value)
```

I know this works because, if I select `value[0]` , it will only select the first row, i.e 04-Nov-22, 0.9872,  145.19

I have a user input, where a user will input the date in the same format **%d-%b-%y**.
How do I make it so that when the user enters that date, it checks if that date exists, and if so returns its index which should be 0.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a loop but pre-process the DataFrame:

```
s = df.reset_index().set_index('Date')['index']
```

Then, access the index per date using [`get`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.get.html) with a default value if missing:

```
user_input = '04-Nov-22'
out = s.get(user_input, 'date not found')
```

Output: `0`